# Trouble getting c++ program triangle to display correctly

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

first i would like to say i appreciate the help before hand. I need to create a c++ program that takes in a number of rows and displays the number with characters and the number of the row. For example if i put 1 as my number of rows the out put should be the following:

1 would look this is where O is "OH":

```
O1
```

3 would look this this:

```
O1
EE2
OOO3
```

6 would look like this:

```
O1
EE2
OOO3
EEEE4
OOOOO5
EEEEEE6
```

i am only allowed to use while loops to do this.

here is the output that i get when i use 5 for my rows:

```
O1
EE2
OO3
EE4
OO5
```

for the life of me i cannot figure out how to display the characters correct.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n(0);
    int i(1);
    int k(1);
    int even2= 1;
    int odd2=1;

    while(n<1)
    {
        cout<<"Enter number of rows:";
        cin>>n;
    }

    while(i<=n)
    {
        while(k<=i)
        {
           if(k%2 == 0)
           {
               while(even2<=k)
               {
                   cout<<"E";
                   even2++;
               }
           }
           else
           {
               while(odd2<=k)
               {
                  cout<<"O";
                  odd2++;
               }
           }
           k++;
        }
        cout<<i<<endl;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: yes just being a beginner i really need to pay much closer attention to content, and code step  by step but would you mind looking at my edited post? sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Reset the odd2 and even2 variables before you start the printout of "O"/"E".

Comment: not gonna lie, not exactly following you on that one. haha

Comment: i just got it working correctly. thanks captain giraffe, when i sent odd2 and even 2 to zero before the loop and k<4 and not k<=4 it worked correctly